# como concatenar um objeto em função assincrona?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Olá estou desenvolvendo um site para treinar um pouco de js, mas me deparei com a seguinte situação: Eu tenho um Objeto javascript que eu criei para facilitar as consultas Ajax, porém quando eu estou fazendo as requisições ás vezes um link é resolvido ou terminado(não sei terminologia técnica certa) antes do outro, então isso buga meu site as vezes não mostrando o valores que eu quero(estou usando o método do array push por hora),ai pensei em criar um novo Objeto enquanto faço as requisições com o nome de cada item, para pegar os valores de forma mais fácil e não ter problemas quanto a velocidade dos da resolução dos links, porém quando realizo minha função só retorna o valor do ultimo nome do objeto criado.

para exemplificar melhor:

Objeto:

```js
ExchangeInfo = {
  mercadobitcoin:{
    name:"mercadobitcoin",
    bch:{
      orderbook:"https://www.mercadobitcoin.net/api/BCH/orderbook/"
    }
  },
  braziliex:{
    name:"braziliex",
    bch:{
      orderbook:"https://braziliex.com/api/v1/public/orderbook/bch_brl"
    }
  },
  negociecoins:{
    name:"negociecoins",
    bch:{
      orderbook:"https://broker.negociecoins.com.br/api/v3/bchbrl/orderbook"
    }
  }
};
```

Função:

```js
v = {};
function getApiLinks() {
  for (prop in ExchangeInfo){
    var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xml.open("GET",ExchangeInfo[prop]["bch"]["orderbook"],true);
    xml.send();
    xml.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if(this.status == 200 && this.readyState == 4){
        myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        v[ExchangeInfo[prop]["name"]]=this.responseText;
        return v[ExchangeInfo[prop]["name"]] = myObj; // resolução parcial que só retorna o ultimo valor consultado exemplo abaixo.
        // return v.push(myObj); resolução atual intermitente
      }
    }
  }
}
```

objeto retornado:

```js
{
  negociecoins:{
    ask[
      //dados retornados pelo ajax
    ],
    bid:[
      //dados retornados pelo ajax
    ]
  }
}
```

Objeto esperado:

```js
{
  mercadobitcoin:{
    ask[
      //dados retornados pelo ajax
    ],
    bid:[
      //dados retornados pelo ajax
    ]
  },
  braziliex:{
    ask[
      //dados retornados pelo ajax
    ],
    bid:[
      //dados retornados pelo ajax
    ]
  },
  negociecoins:{
    ask[
      //dados retornados pelo ajax
    ],
    bid:[
      //dados retornados pelo ajax
    ]
  }
}
```

Desculpa se a pergunta ficou muito longa, tentei dar o máximo de informações possível.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tem como fazer isso desta forma porque o `for` é assíncrono ao Ajax e retornará o último processamento dentro dele.

O `return` usado também retornará `undefined` porque o `for` irá terminar antes que a primeira requisição (do total de 3) do Ajax seja processada, exatamente por ser assíncrono.

Para obter o resultado desejado, você teria que fazer isso de forma síncrona, chamando cada requisição Ajax por vez, sem usar o laço `for` para fazer requisições. Pode fazer usando uma função conforme exemplo abaixo:

```
v = {};
function getApiLinks() {
   var array = []; // array para guardar os nomes dos objetos
   for (prop in ExchangeInfo){
      // adicionar os nomes dos objetos para usar no Ajax
      array.push(ExchangeInfo[prop]["name"]);
   }
   // variável que irá contar quantas vezes
   // a função será chamada
   var conta = 0;

   function Ajax(){
      var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xml.open("GET",ExchangeInfo[array[conta]]["bch"]["orderbook"],true);
      xml.send();
      xml.onreadystatechange = function(){
         if(this.status == 200 && this.readyState == 4){
            myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            //v[ExchangeInfo[prop]["name"]]=this.responseText;
            v[array[conta]] = myObj; // resolução parcial que só retorna o ultimo valor consultado exemplo abaixo.
            // return v.push(myObj); resolução atual intermitente
            conta++;
            // chama novamente a função
            // até que "conta" seja menor que
            // o númrero de itens na array
            if(conta < array.length) Ajax();
         }
      }
   }
   Ajax(); // chama a função

  return v; // retorna o objeto
}

console.log(getApiLinks());
```

O `return v;` irá devolver:

```
braziliex:
{asks: Array(203), bids: Array(32)}

mercadobitcoin:
{asks: Array(1000), bids: Array(247)}

negociecoins:
{ask: Array(162), bid: Array(51)}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, funcionou direitinho, não sabia que não dava para fazer com requisições assíncronas pois estava dando certo com o array, mas não com objeto. valeu mesmo resposta.

Comment: só não marquei a resposta com útil antes, porque minha pontuação era muito baixa.